# Unity Android: Keep save after deleting app?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, saving-data

I have created an app where you can unlock certain things and also you can buy them with real money. Because of this it would be a shame if a user loses all his unlocked things when removing the app.

At first I used PlayerPrefs, but that isn't safe for these kind of things I learned. Also PlayerPrefs get cleared when removing the app.

Then I found out how to serialize my data and save it to the "PersistentDataPath". This will be much safer, but it also gets cleared when removing the app.

Is there a way, besides working with a external server, in which I can store my players unlocked things and it won't get deleted when they remove the app? I also read something about the permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE not allowing this.

I just want to avoid raging players who delete the app and reinstall it later and then figuring out everything they paid for is gone.

Thanks in advance lads!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Google Play Games they have a "Saved Games" feature. That way the savegame will even survive when the user gets a new phone.

https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames